# Aligning two equations with a 'multiline' bracket around them to previous equations

Tags: align, amsmath, alignment

I am trying to align a set of solutions of an equation to previous equations at the position of their equal signs. Next to the set equations is a bracket that goes over both lines. The code I already have is equivalent to the following:

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
    x^2 & = 1 \\
    \Rightarrow \quad \left\{
    \begin{array}{r l}
        x & = - 1 \\
        x & = 1
    \end{array}
    \right. \\
    x & = 1
\end{align*}
```

[image: Output]
Is there or can I set another marker to use for alignment? Are there other equation environments or solutions for the bracket itself that would make this obsolete?
Additionally, is there an option to reduce the space left to the equal signs of the last two equations to 'normal' size (to comparison I copied the last solution inside the normal equation environment)?
Edit: The last problem can be fixed by using `aligned` instead of `array`(Credit to @Teddy van Jerry).

Comment: You can use `aligned` environment instead of `array` without the `{r l}` specification. (This sets a normal space around `=`.)

Comment: That works perfectly, thansk a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a solution provided your equation is not so complicated.
The main concept is to overlap the part to the right of `=` using `\mathrlap` and compensate the width using `\hphantom` (This is needed because you certainly want the equation be centered.).
`\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` after `\right.` is used to remove the additional space after `\right.`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            x^2 = \mathrlap{1} & \\
            \Rightarrow \quad \left\{
            \begin{aligned}
                x & = \mathrlap{-1} \\
                x & = \mathrlap{1}
            \end{aligned}
            \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace & \hphantom{-1} \\
            x = \mathrlap{1} &
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> TIP: `mathtools` auto includes the `amsmath` package and is more stable.

[image: Result]